# Rest api without serializer in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to create an API without a serializer in Django? How to do that? What is the use of serializers and can we customize the error response of serializers? For example
serializers error response will be as follow:

```
{
    "first_name":["This field is required"],
    "last_name":["This field is required"],
    "email":"["This field is required"],
}
```

but I want to return a custom error response. Suppose any of the fields is not validate then I want to display an error response in the following format

```
{
    "status":"Error",
    "text":"Email not provided"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jason Morse, many questions but I will try to focus on the custom error response. Let's say that you need to override the error message for the `first_name` field, then you can do something like `first_name = serializers.CharField(error_messages={'required': 'Custom error message'})`.